# NMSSH : iOS - Unable to establish ssh session

Tags: ios, ssh

I am trying to establish a SSH connection to a device using NMSSH. However, I am unable to establish a SSH connection and the error message returned isn't every helpful either:

NMSSH: libssh2 (v1.4.3) initialized
2014-03-23 12:41:36.940 Learning[1026:3707] NMSSH: Start x.x.x.x resolution
2014-03-23 12:41:46.936 Learning[1026:60b] Session is not established
2014-03-23 12:41:46.938 Learning[1026:3707] NMSSH: Socket connection to x.x.x.x on port 22 failed   with reason -2, trying next address...

Server IP is correct. What could be the reason, can someone provide any pointers ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFSocketConnectToAddress

Comment: -2 means socket timeout. I expect there is nothing listening at port 22 or it refuses to respond...

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, @rene. I was suspecting it could be the timeout and increased the timeout to see if it works, and that did work.

Comment: Post as an answer what you did